# Show regular price in custom place on product page woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I try to show regular price before add to cart. This code must work only for one catgory. How to change this code?

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'basic_price', 15 ); 
function basic_price() {
   $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true); 
   $formatted_price = wc_price( $price ); 
    $product_categories = array('laminat');
    if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $_product->get_id() ) ) 
    echo '<span class="ri ri-clock">Стоимость упаковки: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'. $formatted_price .'</span></span>'; // Print new html with title and price
}
```

this code works but for all categories:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'basic_price', 15 ); 
function basic_price() {
   $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true); 
   $formatted_price = wc_price( $price ); 
    echo '<span class="ri ri-clock">Стоимость упаковки: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'. $formatted_price .'</span></span>'; // Print new html with title and price
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. This code show regular price before add to cart in custom category.

```
  add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'basic_price', 15 ); 
    function basic_price() {
      $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true); 
      $formatted_price = wc_price( $price ); 
      if( has_term( ['laminat'], 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<p class="vel_costpack">Стоимость упаковки: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'. $formatted_price .'</span></p>'; // Print new html with title and price
      }
    }
```